# Leave event not called when hiding a widget

Tags: qt

I wants to hide a QLabel widget when the mouse is released on it. Everything works fine, except that the leaveEvent is not called when I call QLabel::hide(), inside mouseReleaseEvent.

The method is called properly when I leave the label normally (while it is shown), but not when I call the hide() method. I tried to call hide() outside the mouseReleaseEvent (using a QTimer), but leaveEvent is still not called.

The result is that when I display the label again, enterEvent is not called the first time the mouse enter the widget, and I have to move outside (to call leaveEvent), and then inside again.

So my question is why leaveEvent is not called when I hide the label (the mouse is still over the widget), and is there a way to force the call of leaveEvent whenever I want.

I hope my explanations are not too confused. Thanks.

Edit:
Here is a simple example that doesn't work for me:

```
struct Label : public QLabel
{
    Label(QGraphicsScene *scene)
    {
        item.setWidget(this);
        setText("Text");
        scene->addItem(&item);
        setMinimumWidth(200);
        setMinimumHeight(200);
        show();
    }

    ~Label()
    {
        item.setWidget(NULL);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {
        std::cout << "mouseReleaseEvent" << std::endl;
        hide();
    }

    void enterEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter" << std::endl;
    }

    void leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {
        std::cout << "Leave" << std::endl;
    }

    QGraphicsProxyWidget item;
};
```

Comment: Just a quick idea (trick): move mouse cursor from the label soon before you hide it. Will the `leaveEvent` trigger in that case?

Comment: Yes, if I press, leave the widget area, and release, the leave event is called. But if I release the mouse inside the widget, even if I move (outside and back inside), it is not called.

Comment: Well, now try to move cursor programmatically. For example with `QCursor::setPos()` function.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't work if I do the setPos() and hide() in the mouseReleaseEvent, but it does if I call hide() later (Qt have to come back in the event loop). But it's so dirty that I don't think I can handle it. Is there not another way to do this ? I mean it's pretty basic GUI stuff here. Thanks anyway, I have a backup solution at least.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I called it a trick. Btw, what Qt version do you use? I cannot reproduce it on Qt4.8.x (Windows). The LeaveEvent is called pretty well.

Comment: I am using Qt5.1, msvc2010. I don't know if it is related, but I am working with a QGraphicsView.

Comment: Works fine for me on Qt 5.1.1.